# Using Rackspace Cloud Sites with external DNS

Tags: dns, rackspace, dnsimple

Rackspace.com offer cloudsites a one stop managed LAMP stack. One of it's features is a Wordpress blog, often you require just a blog.

Cloudsites encourages the use of pointing your nameservers to it, but this isn't always wanted.

How can I use an external DNS provider?

Answer (score 0):

This can be completed using ALIAS records from DNSimple and other providers. Use the testing URL as the URL and the provider will complete the re-direct and clocking of the domain so it looks like a CNAME.